# Load testing email notifications with jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter test which sends a reset email notification to a specific gmail account. When sending 500 emails within a couple minutes I only get roughly 250 of them. What I think is happening is that gmail is blocking or throttling the amount of email received by one account. Is there a way I can get around this limitation or is there another email client i can use?

I thought about feeding a csv file with a few different email addresses.

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: If your emails are getting caught in gmail's anti-spam, there is a good chance they'll still get caught if you use several destination addresses - you're still spamming the same gmail server from the same source. You could also be violating gmail's terms of use. Your best bet is to setup your own mail server.

Comment: @RaGe, why not write your answer instead of commenting ? Commenting make the question appears as not answered while I think your comment is a valid answer . Thanks

Comment: I don't think my answer is definitive, I don't even have access to gmail terms of use from where I am right now. Hence comment.